# Debugging instantiated classes in Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, attributes, adminhtml, php

In PHP there `get_object_vars`, `get_class` and methods that return information about the class, we can use the Magento `Zend_Debug::dump()`, `Mage::log()` and up `XDebug`, but during module development in Magento, where we need overwrite some part of the administrative panel, for that we must look for the correct classes.

How to get list of all instantiated classes accessing a page of Magento?

Example: `X` user accessed `Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attribute`, how to generate a Debug with the list of all classes that were instantiated when the user accessed the Manage Attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getModelInstance`

```
public function getModelInstance($modelClass='', $constructArguments=array())
    {
        $className = $this->getModelClassName($modelClass);
        if (class_exists($className)) {
            Varien_Profiler::start('CORE::create_object_of::'.$className);
            $obj = new $className($constructArguments);
            Varien_Profiler::stop('CORE::create_object_of::'.$className);
            return $obj;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

you can use that method to find all the classes instantiated.